Problema al aplicar set_charset en PHP y MySqli
Tengo un problema con la función set_charset que he puesto en la función conexion de la clase class.Database.php y decidi ponerla ahi para no estar seteando cada vez que se llama a otra función de esa misma clase.
Sucede que en este caso no actualiza totalemente la información de respuesta del servidor cuando falla el INSERT despues de haber hecho previamente otro. Ejemplo:
En el archivo insert.php primero vemos la invocación de la funcion insert de la clase class.Usuario.php, como esta función ejecuta una sentencia INSERT me devuelve el ultimo ID del registro insertado con exito. Entonces supongamos que el ultimo ID es 8 por lo tanto ese valor es el resultado devuelto.
Como segunda función invocada es insertNomina de la misma clase y también ejecuta una sentencia INSERT devolviendo lo mismo que comente anteriormente (En caso de éxito el ultimo ID) pero si ocurre alguna falla se supone que devuelve un 0.
Entonces hace el primer INSERT y todo bien devuelve un ID mayor a 0 (porque hubo un registro con éxito) pero cuando intenta hacer el segundo y ocurre una falla devuelve el ID del primer INSERT cuando que lo correcto debería ser 0 ya que por la falla en ese segundo INSERT no hay un registro con éxito.
Ahora si no hay falla en ningún INSERT todo funciona correctamente.
Algo muy curioso que pasa es que cuando el set_charset lo coloco en cada función de class.Database.php todo funciona muy bien.
Porque esta pasando esto??
class.Database.php
<?php
class Database
{
    private static $db_host     = "localhost";
    private static $db_user     = "root";
    private static $db_password = "123";
    private static $db_database = "empresabd";
    
    static function conexion()
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli(self::$db_host, self::$db_user, self::$db_password, self::$db_database);
        $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
        $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
        return $mysqli;
    }
        
    static function select($query, $mysqli)
    {
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        if(isset($result->num_rows))
        {
            if($result->num_rows > 0)
            {
                $rows = self::resultToArray($result);
                $result->free();
                return $rows;
            }
        }
       
        return FALSE;
    }

    static function insert($query, $mysqli)
    {
        $mysqli->multi_query($query);
        $insert_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
        return $insert_id;
    }

    static function update($query, $mysqli)
    {
        $success = $mysqli->query($query);
        return $success;
    }

    static function resultToArray($result)
    {
        $rows = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }  
}
?>

class.Usuario.php
<?php    
include_once("class.Database.php");
    
class Usuario 
{
    public $id_usuario;
    public $nombre;
    public $apellidos;
    public $usuario;
    public $contrasena;
    
    function __construct($id_usuario)
    {
        global $conexion;
        
        $query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id_usuario = $id_usuario";
        $usuario = Database::select($query, $conexion);
        $usuario = $usuario[0];
        $this->id_usuario           = $usuario['id_usuario'];
        $this->nombre               = $usuario['nombre'];
        $this->apellidos            = $usuario['apellidos'];
        $this->usuario              = $usuario['usuario'];
        $this->contrasena           = $usuario['contrasena'];
    }
    
    function updateCorreo($correo)
    {
        global $conexion;
        
        $query = "REPLACE INTO correo SET id_usuario = $this->id_usuario, correo = '$correo'";
        return Database::update($query, $conexion);
    }
    
    # Métodos estáticos
    
    public static function insertNomina($id_usuario, $puesto, $sueldo)
    {
        global $conexion;
        
        $query = "INSERT INTO nomina(id_usuario, puesto, sueldo)
                 VALUES($id_usuario, $puesto, $sueldo)";
        return Database::insert($query, $conexion);
    }
    
    public static function insert($nombre, $apellidos, $usuario, $contrasena)
    {
        global $conexion;
        
        $query = "INSERT INTO usuario(nombre, apellidos, usuario, contrasena)
                 VALUES('$nombre', '$apellidos', '$usuario', '$contrasena')";
        return Database::insert($query, $conexion);
    }
}
?>

insert.php
<?php
include_once("../../clases/class.Usuario.php");

extract($_POST);
# nombre
# apellidos
# correo
# usuario
# contrasena
# puesto
# sueldo

$conexion = Database::conexion();
$conexion->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_WITH_CONSISTENT_SNAPSHOT);

try{
    $id_usuario = Usuario::insert($nombre, $apellidos, $usuario, $contrasena);
    
    if($id_usuario >= 1)
    {
        $id_nomina = Usuario::insertNomina($id_usuario, $puesto, $sueldo);
                
        if($id_nomina >= 1)
        {
            $usuario = new Usuario($id_usuario);
            $updateCorreo = $usuario->updateCorreo($correo);
            
            if($updateCorreo)
            {
                $conexion->commit();
                echo 1;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(2);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(3);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(4);
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    $conexion->rollback();
    echo $e->getMessage();
}finally{
    $conexion->close();
}
?>



NOTA: Dejo claro que la clase class.Database.php no es de mi autoría pero hice una modificación al agregar la función conexión para poder trabajar con lo del COMMIT y ROLLBACK porque originalmente esta clase no esta programada para trabajar con estas sentencias.

Hola. El código se comporta del modo correcto. insert_id devuelve el ID del último INSERT exitoso. Para saber si se insertaron filas o no deberías usar affected_rows. Tu código revela más bien errores de diseño. Por ejemplo, no se entiende por qué usas multi_query, violando el principio de responsabilidad única. Y, conviene preguntarse si en vez de usar insert_id no es mejor implementar integridad referencial y/o disparadores (triggers) en la base de datos. Aquí el problema no parece ser el charset. Deberías replantearte el diseño en su totalidad.

@A.Cedano hola amigo, crees que seria bueno, colocarle la etiqueta revisión-de-código a esta pregunta y darle un tratamiento y/o respuesta a la pregunta "Por que esta pasando esto??", resulta que hasta a mi me interesa ver que respuesta o arquitectura de codigo seria la adecuada implementar ante este error de logica.

en su momento yo tuve problema con este tipo de estructura y despues con el cache de TABLE_SCHEMA

@FranciscoIALover el problema es que Stackoverflow no es tan amplio como ocurre en inglés, donde hay una comunidad y un sitio dedicados específicamente a la revisión de código. Para resolver esto aplicando lo referido en mis comentarios anteriores no hay una respuesta única e intervienen varios factores que escapan al alcance de SO en Español. En primer lugar, que OP decida aplicar esa solución. Luego, habría que ver los diseños de las tablas y por último el código PHP. El problema es que muchos tratan a las bases de datos como ...

... un almacén de datos muerto, sin vida, creyendo que deben dar vida a ese almacén de datos con su propio código, cuando una base de datos es realmente un Sistema Gestor de Bases de Datos, es decir, un sistema capaz por sí mismo de mantener esos datos, para lo cual dispone de reglas, de restricciones, de disparadores, de procedimientos, de manejador de eventos, etc, etc, etc. Una base de datos es más que INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT. Y convendría dejar que ella haga lo que mejor que nadie sabe hacer, no reinventando nosotros la rueda a otro nivel.

ok, capas me hago un sitio donde este tipo de preguntas sean acetadas ... que tal haca https://azk.lh-2.net/ por que hay un the righ way de php pero no veo uno de mysql que ayude a comprender estos paradigmas ...

@A.Cedano y entonces porque si el set_charset lo coloco en cada función insert/update/select si funciona todo bien pero si lo coloco únicamente en la función conexión no funciona correctamente?? Porque pareciera como si no actualizará la caché

Sin tener de frente todo el escenario no podría decirte por qué funciona al poner set_charset por todos lados. Pero ya el hecho de que debas ponerlos por todos lados indica que hay un problema, sea en la codificación de los datos en sí mismos, sea en la configuración del entorno en el que estás trabajando y si es así, debes resolverlo de raíz, configurando todo de modo que no tengas problemas con el juego de carácteres. Pero, como ya dije en comentarios más arriba, el problema aquí es de diseño. Si apuestas por un buen diseño, luego tu código será más limpio y sencillo.

Yo es que cuando veo que por ejemplo mezclas un insert con un update, me hace daño a los ojos. Hay algo que se llama Principio de Responsabilidad única en programación. Un insert es una cosa y un update es otra. Es cierto que se relacionan, pero eso NO tienes que programarlo tú. Eso debería resolverlo la base de datos con algo que se llama integridad referencial. Si tienes eso bien definido, cuando un registro se inserta en una tabla, los datos de la tabla relacionada se actualizan, o si se borra de una tabla, se borran en la tabla relacionada, sin intervención por código.

Para ilustrar mejor lo dicho en mis dos anteriores comentarios, me permito dejar unos enlaces. El primero es sobre el asunto del charset. El otro, es una respuesta ilustrando cómo funciona la integridad referencial. Sólo por demostrar que es un error tratar a las bases de datos como un almacén de datos muerto al que nosotros debemos reanimar mediante código. Te aconsejo que programes sólo aquello que la BD no es capaz de hacer y que dejes que ella haga todo lo que sabe hacer, pues lo hará mejor que tú.

@A.Cedano ya estuve viendo los enlaces que compartiste pero veo que aqui dan soluciones para cuando no se siguen interpretando correctamente los caracteres especiales de los datos obtenidos de una base de datos y mi problema es totalmente diferente, la función set_charset unicamente invocada en la función conexion me esta dando un problemon cuanto a que no actualiza el valor del insert_id de cada sentencia INSERT ejecutada, actualice completamente mi pregunta esperando que asi pueda quedar mas claro.

Como te decía más arriba, una configuración del charset a nivel de la conexión debería bastar. Si el código falla en algún punto y se resuelve aplicando charset, significa que en ese entorno el charset no está bien configurado a otro nivel y deberías corregir ese problema en el origen. Si son los datos lo que están mal, deberías ver por qué está mal codificados o vienen mal codificados. Propongo que nos centremos en el problema y luego podrás resolver todo a nivel global, si quieres. De todo el código que nos expones, ¿en cuál falla exactamente por problemas de charset? ...

... ¿Revisaste en ese contexto donde falla los datos que estás intentando insertar o actualizar, haciendo un var_dump de dichos datos? Ahí podrás verificar si la sentencia está siendo errónea por un problema de codificación, lo cual hace que el INSERT no se realice.

Independientemente de esto, estamos ante un falso problema en el sentido de que los registros dependientes deberían actualizarse sólos en tu base de datos, sea mediante disparadores  (TRIGGERS) sea aplicando las restricciones de integridad referencial. Si es demasiado contenido para ti por ahora, y te da más tranquilidad, podemos intentar resolver este código, pero te recomendaría que profundices luego en esos temas, porque te van a facilitar el trabajo y la integridad de los datos estará mejor garantizada que resolviéndolo con un código que reinventa la rueda.

Volviendo al asunto de resolver este código, ¿si pones un var_dump($_POST); en el escenario donde falla, qué muestra ese var_dump?

Con respecto a la tabla nomina, ¿la columna puesto en dicha tabla es numérica?

@A.Cedano es lo que mas quisiera intentar resolver este código

El fallo se da en la función insert que es ejecutada por la función insertNomina pero unicamente cuando se presenta una falla durante la inserción si no hay falla todo funciona de maravilla

La columna puesto en la tabla nomina es numérica

El var_dump lo hice sobre el objeto mysqli despues de ejecutar las sentencias INSERT la primera prueba es colocando set_charset solo en la función conexion y la segunda es colando set_charset en cada función, los resultados de eso estan en las imagenes que estoy compartiendo en la pregunta

Mis tablas y la base de datos estan con el cotejamiento utf8_general_ci, no se si con eso ya no me vea en la necesidad de usar set_charset??

Ya, pero el fallo aparece claro en las capturas. Lo que está ocurriendo es un problema de las restricciones de integridad referencial. El var_dump  que te propongo ahora es sobre los datos, o sea, var_dump($_POST); y verificar que los datos que intentas insertar existen en las tablas dependientes así como verificar al mismo tiempo que no haya un problema de codificación en los datos que están llegando. Luego, confírmame si la columna puesto es de tipo numérica, pues si es varchar esa consulta no podría funcionar.

@A.Cedano la columna puesto es numérica

Continuemos el debate en el chat.

El error que estás teniendo es de restricción de llave foránea al intentar insertar un registro huérfano en una tabla dependiente.
Este tipo de errores no se resuelven cambiando el charset, y así debe ser, porque las restricciones de llave foránea existen precisamente para no permitir que haya registros huérfanos cuando se requieren datos consistentes.
La solución al error es garantizar por código y mediante control de las entradas que el usuario proporcione datos válidos.
Para tales fines, lo mejor es escribir el código implementando manejo de errores desde el principio. Esto te quitará varios if de encima, por ejemplo, lanzando una Excepcion en los métodos insert y update de Database y capturándola en el catch.
Así el código queda más limpio y más claro.
Otra incongruencia que se ve, es que pasas en parámetro la conexión a ella misma en llamadas como esta: return Database::insert($query, $conexion); Eso evidencia un mal diseño. Si  insert es un método de Database, y allí está la conexión, ¿por qué pasarla de nuevo en parámetro? Vamos a intentar que Database se parezca un poco a un envoltorio real de la conexión, aunque esto no es perfecto y se podría mejorar bastante1, pero meterse en eso nos alejaría ahora del propósito principal de la pregunta.
Simplemente en Database crearemos un propiedad $mysqli, la asignaremos en conexion y usaremos esa propiedad cada vez que vayamos a hacer una consulta. También creamos los métodos de transacciones. Por brevedad lo haremos así, lo propio sería una clase que extienda de Mysqli, teniendo así todos sus métodos, sin necesidad de redefinirlos.
Aplicando todo lo dicho, el código quedaría así:
Database
class Database
{

    private static $db_host     = "localhost";
    private static $db_user     = "elUsuario";
    private static $db_password = "123";
    private static $db_database = "laBD";

    /*
        Propiedad que representa la conexión
    */
    private static $mysqli;

    static function conexion()
    {
        /*
            Activamos el manejo de errores
            Obsérvese que en los  métodos usamos
            bloques try ... catch
            y que relanzamos la Exception con throw new Exception($e)
            lo cual permitirá capturar cualquier error en el llamador
            por eso podemos quitar todos los if que había
        */
        $driver = new mysqli_driver();
        $driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL;
        try
        {
            self::$mysqli = new mysqli(self::$db_host, self::$db_user, self::$db_password, self::$db_database);
            self::$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
            self::$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
            return self::$mysqli;
        }
        catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
        {
            error_log($e->__toString());
            echo "No se pudo conectar a la BD";
            throw new Exception($e);
        }
    }

    static function select($query)
    {
        try
        {
            $result = self::$mysqli->query($query);
            if(isset($result->num_rows))
            {
                if($result->num_rows > 0)
                {
                    $rows = self::resultToArray($result);
                    $result->free();
                    return $rows;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
        {
            error_log($e->__toString());
            echo "Error SQL: $query";
            throw new Exception($e);
        }
    }

    static function insert($query)
    {
        try
        {
            self::$mysqli->multi_query($query);
            $insert_id = self::$mysqli->insert_id;
            return $insert_id;
        }
        catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
        {
            error_log($e->__toString());
            echo "Error SQL: $query";
            throw new Exception($e);
        }
    }

    static function update($query)
    {
        try
        {
            $success = self::$mysqli->query($query);
            return $success;
        }
        catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
        {
            error_log($e->__toString());
            echo "Error SQL: $query";
            throw new Exception($e);
        }
    }

    static function resultToArray($result)
    {
        $rows = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }

    /*
        Redefinición de métodos, para poder llamarlos
        desde cualquier parte....
        Lo mejor es que la clase extienda de Mysqli
    */
    static function begin_transaction($type)
    {
        self::$mysqli->begin_transaction($type);
    }

    static function commit()
    {
        self::$mysqli->commit();
    }

    static function rollback()
    {
        self::$mysqli->rollback();
    }

    static function close()
    {
        self::$mysqli->close();
    }
}


Usuario
class Usuario
{
    public $id_usuario;
    public $nombre;
    public $apellidos;
    public $usuario;
    public $contrasena;

    function __construct($id_usuario)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id_usuario = $id_usuario";
        $usuario = Database::select($query);
        $usuario = $usuario[0];
        $this->id_usuario           = $usuario['id_usuario'];
        $this->nombre               = $usuario['nombre'];
        $this->apellidos            = $usuario['apellidos'];
        $this->usuario              = $usuario['usuario'];
        $this->contrasena           = $usuario['contrasena'];
    }

    function updateCorreo($correo)
    {
        $query = "REPLACE INTO correo SET id_usuario = $this->id_usuario, correo = '$correo'";
        return Database::update($query);
    }

    # Métodos estáticos

    public static function insertNomina($id_usuario, $puesto, $sueldo)
    {
        $id_usuario=15;
        $query = "INSERT INTO nomina(id_usuario, puesto, sueldo)
                 VALUES($id_usuario, $puesto, $sueldo)";
        return Database::insert($query);
    }

    public static function insert($nombre, $apellidos, $usuario, $contrasena)
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO usuario(nombre, apellidos, usuario, contrasena)
                 VALUES('$nombre', '$apellidos', '$usuario', '$contrasena')";
        return Database::insert($query);
    }
}


insert.php
Es un código totalmente, limpio, capturando las Excepciones, que se lanzarán cuando algo falle en la clase envoltorio.
#Convendría sanear esta entrada
extract($_POST);
#Conectamos a la BD
Database::conexion();
#Iniciamos modo transacción
Database::begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_WITH_CONSISTENT_SNAPSHOT);

try
{
    $id_usuario = Usuario::insert($nombre, $apellidos, $usuario, $contrasena);
    $id_nomina = Usuario::insertNomina($id_usuario, $puesto, $sueldo);
    $usuario = new Usuario($id_usuario);
    $updateCorreo = $usuario->updateCorreo($correo);
    Database::commit();
    echo "Transacción confirmada con id_usuario: $id_usuario, id_nomina: $id_nomina correo: $correo";
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    Database::rollback();
    printf("Error: %s", $e->getMessage());
}finally{
    Database::close();
}


Notas

Para un ejemplo de clase envoltorio puedes ver esta respuesta, en ella no tienes que redefinir los métodos de la conexión tales como commit, rollback, etc, porque la clase extiende de mysqli y en consecuencia posee ya esos métodos.


Que tal A. Cedano he probado el código que propones y soluciona mi problema, más sin embargo he revisado el enlace que compartes sobre la propuesta de una clase envoltoria y me ha entrado la espina de trabajar con este tipo de clase pero al revisar el código que propusiste en esa respuesta me han quedado ciertas dudas las cuales te comento

Mencionas que no se puede usar el bloque try-catch en el constructor de la clase cuando se usa mysqli y entonces el constructor del padre tendría que trabajarlo asi como lo propones en esa respuesta, es decir sin encerrarlo en el try-catch??

También otra duda que me surge es tendría que definir esa función getInstance() para obtener la instancia de la conexión?? Qué no se supone que al instanciar la clase hija se obtiene tambien toda la información del padre por la cuestión de la herencia??
